# Facebook iOS login

Tags: objective-c, ios7, facebook

I have successfully implemented `Login with Facebook` using the approach specified in [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started). Now the issue I am having here is, "Logout" button after successful authentication.

As per my requirement, whenever user navigates to this screen they should always see "Login with Facebook" instead of "`Logout`" and click again "`Login with Facebook`". Is there any configuration I can use to perform this? Any input would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Then just destroy fbSession on viewWillDisappear method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in viewWillAppear() in your code

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Let me try it.